# Accessibility not working correctly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, accessibility

Hey i have a `UITableView` with some Custom Cells. Inside the Cells are some Images and 2 Labels.
My Problem is that i want to hide the Images, so that the `VoiceOver` Function ignore the Images, but it doesn´t work at all:

```
newsCell.titleImageView.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
newsCell.boardNoteImage.isAccessibilityElement = NO;
newsCell.boardNoteImage.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
newsCell.titleImageView.accessibilityElementsHidden = YES;
```

What could be the Problem?

Comment: May be cell reusability would be the issue. Where have you put this code?

Comment: its in cellForRowAtIdndexPath, at the moment i test it with only one cell but still not work...

Comment: How is VoiceOver actually behaving - what, if anything, is it reading out for these cells? FWIW, you generally don't need accessibilityElementHidden on simple controls like images and labels; isAccessibilityElement should be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`accessibilityElements`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/objectivec/nsobject/1615147-accessibilityelements) to access elements in custom table view cell.
Do like:

```
accessibilityElements = [Label1, Label2]
```

You will only read two labels in single cell and skip image in accessibility.